Could New Order theoretically be transferred One for All style?
New Order, Star and Stripe's (from now on I'll call her Star for quickness) quirk, allows its user to impose "rules" on their environment by touching something, saying its true name (this is important since New Order didn't work on Toumura since he was having an identity crisis and didn't know if he was Toumura, Tenko, or AFO), and what the rule is.
For example, Star could've touched a rock, said "rock", and then said, "the rock will float" and the rock would float. This may be an oversimplification, as there are several conditions, like the perception rule (only applies to living things), the wordplay rule (Star could not impose rules on something she hadn't touched, Toumura explained it as saying, "she cannot say anyone within this specific block of air will die.") and possibly a few other conditions I'm missing.
But would it be technically possible for Star to walk up to someone, say their name (or the name of her quirk), and then say, for example, "New Order will be transferred to XYZ person." Or "XYZ person can now use New Order," or "upon ABC condition or occurrence (for example, Star's death), New Order will be transferred to XYZ person," or does that violate the wordplay rule?
